# How can I install a local package in a docker container?

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, npm-install

I have two local (custom) NPM packages that I've used before. When I install them with `npm i parentFolder/package1 parentFolder/package2`, they install just fine. However, when I add them to my package.json file, and then copy / npm install in my DockerFile, I get an error saying `"Could not install from "x" as it does not contain a package.json file."`. I honestly don't know what to make of this, since it does have a package.json file, and it installs just fine otherwise.

Is there a special step that I need to take for custom packages to work in docker, or am I just lost somehow? I've been staring at this error so long that my brain's a mess, so I probably forgot to add some details. If I forgot something you need to know in order to help, please let me know.

---

Docker-compose file:

```
volumes:
    - ./sprinklers:/app
    # - sprinklers_node_modules:/app/node_modules/
    - ./sprinklers/node_modules_temp:/app/node_modules/
    # - sprinklers_persistent:/app/.node-persist/
    - ./sprinklers/.node-persist:/app/.node-persist/
```

As you can see, I was using named volumes, but tried going to mounted ones to see what happened.

DockerFile:

```
FROM node:14.16.0-slim

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install
```

The COPY statements here were removed, since all files are mounted in the docker-compose file.

Comment: You should consider showing your Dockerfile, possibly, you are mounting the file or using the mounted files erroneously.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I updated the question with (snippets from) both the compose file and the DockerFile.

Comment: `The COPY statements here were removed, since all files are mounted in the docker-compose file` <= the volumes will be mounted when your create a container out of the image using `docker-compose run .....`, not when you are actually building the image. What is wrong ? your packages are not inside the image when your try to install them at build time.

Comment: @Zeitounator I'm amazed. I swear I copied both package.json and the folder containing the modules in the DockerFile before, and it still didn't work then, and now it does. Thanks for pointing that one out